# Which desktop environment does Zorin OS use and how to get for Ubuntu?

Tags: desktop-environments

Which is the Desktop Environment of Zorin OS and is there any way to get it on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Zorin OS use Gnome 3 Desktop Environment with customized themes. To install Gnome 3 use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Then you need to get the themes from Zorin OS and apply to your Gnome installation. Since Zorin OS uses Ubuntu as base for it's packages it's simplier to install Zorin than to apply the themes to Ubuntu.

To install ZorinOS themes open Terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zorinos-themes
```

To install ZorinOS icons open Terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) type the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/icons2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zorinos-icons
```

Comment: See also [this article](https://bigdaddylinux.com/zorin-os-theme-on-any-distribution/) for additional Gnome extensions, fonts and other tweaks to get it looking more like Zorin.

I had some visual problems with this theme on a fresh Ubuntu 19.10 - mainly, the switch control has some cryptic (chinese?) symbols on top of them. (This was bad enough to make me go back to the default theme - if someone knows how to fix this, please post?)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record:
Zorin OS 12.2 Lite uses XFCE4.

//*edit*:

You can install it by writing in terminal:

```
sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: OK, how do you get it for Ubuntu?

Comment: `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop` will install xfce. xfce is the environment used by Xubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you review [How to Write a Good Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659), and consider expanding your answer.