# Getting the desktop environment from zorin os 11 on ubuntu/other ubuntu based distros?

Tags: desktop-environments

Trying to get the desktop environment from Zorin os 11 on ubuntu/other ubuntu based distros?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which desktop environment does Zorin OS use and how to get for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469548/which-desktop-environment-does-zorin-os-use-and-how-to-get-for-ubuntu) (<-be aware this is quite old question and now, gnome3 is default in Ubuntu too...)

Comment: Distrowatch [says](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=zorin) that Zorin 11 has GNOME and LXDE desktops. You can install both from repositories. For theming see duplicate above.

Comment: Tried getting the theming with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469548/which-desktop-environment-does-zorin-os-use-and-how-to-get-for-ubuntu) but ended up with the newer desktop environment from Zorin 12 and up, idk may have been user error but really looking for the one from Zorin 11?

Comment: Zorin 11 is not supported anymore from the developers, so not sure if the themes are available somewhere...