# Trying to install Zorin OS theme 404: Not Found

Tags: themes, ppa

Trying to install Zorin themes on a VM using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469548/which-desktop-environment-does-zorin-os-use-and-how-to-get-for-ubuntu).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zorinos-themes
```

However I get this error, I am not sure if it's an issue with my computer/VM or the packages itself.

```
Atteint :1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Atteint :2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Atteint :3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Ign :4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err :5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP : 185.125.190.52 443]
Atteint :6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Atteint :7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Lecture des listes de paquets…
Dépôt : « deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu/ jammy main »
Description :
themes uploaded on http://www.NoobsLab.com PPA
For exact theme version and support visit on site and see themes page
Plus d'informations : https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/themes
Ajout du dépôt.
Found existing deb entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-ubuntu-themes-jammy.list
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-ubuntu-themes-jammy.list
Found existing deb-src entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-ubuntu-themes-jammy.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-ubuntu-themes-jammy.list
Adding key to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/noobslab-ubuntu-themes.gpg with fingerprint 4FA44A478284A18C1BA4A9CAD530E028F59EAE4D
```

Comment: Installing themes from deb, and especially PPA seems an overkill - why not just copy/paste them? Archives [here](https://github.com/ZorinOS/zorin-desktop-themes/releases)

Answer (score 2):

This PPA doesn't have packages for Ubuntu 22.04.

If you look into the PPA page [https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/themes](https://launchpad.net/%7Enoobslab/+archive/ubuntu/themes) , you'll see that the latest Ubuntu release that was supported is 18.10 (cosmic).

The PPA is obsolete.

Comment: Thanks would you mind telling me how you found that out?

Comment: I found that out from the error message. You an also see https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/themes